# How to call keyup on multiple elements simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code which I believe could be written in a better format but don't know how.

Code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        const $title = $('#id_title');
        const $titleLabel = $('#title_label');
        const $description = $('#id_description');
        const $descriptionLabel = $('#description_label');


        $title.keyup(function () {
            if ($title && $title.val() > 0) {
                $titleLabel.addClass('freeze');
                if ($description && $description.val() > 0) {
                        $titleNext.prop('disabled', false);
                }
            } else {
                $titleLabel.removeClass('freeze');
                $titleNext.prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });

        $description.keyup(function () {
            if ($description && $description.val() > 0) {
                $descriptionLabel.addClass('freeze');
                if ($title && $title.val() > 0) {
                        $titleNext.prop('disabled', false);
                }
            } else {
                $descriptionLabel.removeClass('freeze');
                $titleNext.prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
```

How can I put `$title` and `$description` into one line like `$('#id_title', '#id_description').keyup(...` but using the variables declared above?

Thanks!

Comment: create a `function` ... use that as the callback for `$xxx.keyup` (where xxx is title and description) ... the function needs to be smart though

Comment: That makes sense. Someone recently told me that `onX` events are now considered bad practice. Does this not hold true here? Edit: I guess `onX` events are standard practice in react so maybe I understood it wrong.

Comment: you can also add the listner to its parent tag

Answer (score 1):

You use a comma in the selector to differentiate elements. For example:

`$("#id1, #id2").keyup(function());`

Or, you can also use `add()`:

`$("#id1").add("#id2").keyup(function());`

https://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: I understand that but at the bottom of my post I had explained that I want to use the variables declared above (for reuse).

Comment: When it comes to reusing code, functions would be your best bet since you can either pass in different parameters on each call or within it loop through your variables. Though I think that might overcomplicate some things and you could probably find a simpler solution.

Comment: Okay, so as they were saying above I assume? Something like a `onclick` or `onkeyup` callback function?

Comment: Yeah that might be your best bet

Comment: How does this help with using different variables inside the callback though?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it, I'm not convinced this is better though - sometimes even though two functions look identical (except for external variables in this case) I believe it is clearer to use code like you have

However, this should work

```
$(function () {
    const $title = $('#id_title');
    const $titleLabel = $('#title_label');
    const $description = $('#id_description');
    const $descriptionLabel = $('#description_label');

    $('#id_title,#id_description').keyup(function () {
        const index = +(this.id === 'id_description'); // will be 0 if this is id_title, otherwise 1
        const a = [$title, $description][index];
        const b = [$titleLabel, $descriptionLabel][index];
        const c = [$description, $title][index];
        
        if (a && a.val() > 0) {
            b.addClass('freeze');
            if (c && c.val() > 0) {
                $titleNext.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        } else {
            b.removeClass('freeze');
            $titleNext.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is a little less readable. I will probably go with the callback function as mentioned above. Thanks for taking the time to respond!